Proguard Keep Interface Variable Names for Mybatis
Proguard cannot keep method variable names in interfaces no matter what kind of -keep options I give it. I tried:
-keep interface com.xxx.data.mapper.* {*;} and -keepparameternames
I also tried to add -parameters option to the compiler. But none of them worked.
I need to keep variable names in order for Mybatis to bind the methods to the SQL queries defined in XML files. Otherwise Mybatis throws BindingException after obfuscation.
Could anyone explain why Proguard cannot do it even if I skip interface obfuscation? If javac doesn't keep the variable names, how could Mybatis work without obfuscation?

I know nothing about Proguard, but if this is about referencing parameter from within MyBatis' mapper statements, you can name parameters explicitly using @Param annotation. I also found a possibly related answer.
